# pandas filter column1 and replace its values in column2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In the column 1 I want to filter all users looking for specific one and than replace value for this specific user in different column.

So in table 1 is what I got and table 2 what output I need:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M5f6.png)

Based on these tables: Filter all XXXX in User column and replace their status for Expired

For the past few hours I have been trying to change my code multiple times but it seems like nothing fully works.

Comment: Hi! The example image you include is helpful. I think it would be preferable if you could include the example snippet directly in your post. You could try `df.to_markdown()` or `df.to_csv()`, to convert your existing data frame into a post-able format.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a loc on your dataframe? for example:

```
df.loc[df["User"] == "XXXX", "Status"] = "Expired"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[ your_condition, 'column1' ] = df.loc[ your_condition, 'column2' ]
```